# Evaluation of a trained-on-generated images Tesseract 4 LSTM model against real images

Tags: lstm, ocr, tesseract, tesstrain

I have trained a Tesseract 4 LSTM model against a set of ~30,000 ground truth images that I generated (as opposed to using "real" images from scanned works, of which I do not have enough to reliably train a model).

The model works well (or at least better than `eng`, on which it is based). The image generation script has several parameters that I can adjust, but I'd like to do that in a more "ordered" way than just eyeballing the output, so I'd like to generate metrics based on accuracy across a (much smaller) set of real-world images.

However, it is not clear to me how you can take a set of line images and ground truth text files and generate the required files to run `lstmeval` on the new model. How do you generate the data to feed to `lstmeval` when the evaluation images are not related to the images actually used to train the model in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the `.ltsmf` files needed for the evaluation like this, assuming the evaluation ground-truth is in `tesstrain/data/eval-ground-truth`:

```
cd tesstrain
make lists MODEL_NAME=eval
```

This will generate a file `data/eval/all-lstmf`, which contains a list of all the `.lstmf` files generated. The `list.eval` contains only a subset, as the ground truth corpus is partitioned into evaluation and training sets (according to `RATIO_TRAIN`).

You can then run `lstmeval`:

```
lstmeval \
    --model data/your_model.traineddata  \
    --eval_listfile data/eval/all-lstmf
```

Producing something like this (the mistake below was added to the ground truth of one `.gt.txt` file to provoke an error for example purposes):

```
Warning: LSTMTrainer deserialized an LSTMRecognizer!
Truth:TThoſe hypocrites that live amongſt us,
OCR  :Those hypocrites that live amongst us,
At iteration 0, stage 0, Eval Char error rate=1.282051, Word error rate=8.333333
```

If there are no errors (as it was in this case), it looks like:

```
Warning: LSTMTrainer deserialized an LSTMRecognizer!
At iteration 0, stage 0, Eval Char error rate=0.000000, Word error rate=0.000000
```